# No audio on Flash videos - Both FF and IE

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, audio, troubleshooting, flash

Windows XP Pro. I have suddenly lost audio on Flash videos on both FF and IE. Googled till I am blue in the face, tried all the registry fixes (wavemapper=msacm32.drv), uninstalled and re-installed Flash 10 plugin, nothing works.

Playing MP3 files and other system sounds works fine so it is just limited to Flash.

This is getting really annoying. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the Flash Player, then go to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer and install the newest version.

Comment: What does the `promoid` do?

Comment: Sounds like some sort of promotional link.

Comment: Is this a spam answer? I already have version 10.0.32.18 of the Flash plugin. That promoid link would install the same version, wouldn't it? Am I missing something?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, just go to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ for the uninhibited link.  I agree with the solution, though, as I've had this problem and fixed it this way.  Uninstall any/all versions of flash, and then make sure to install *2* versions: 1 for FF/Safari/Opera, and 1 for IE

Comment: I didn't add the "promoID" parameter. I opened www.adobe.com, clicked "Get Flash Player", and copied the URL I was sent to.  Apparently it's left over from when I downloaded the trial version of Flash (development environment) a few days ago.  No, it's not spam and I don't get a dime if the original URL is clicked.  I'm going to edit that out, since it was unintentional.

Answer (score 0):

What did you uninstall it with ?
Using the in-built uninstaller will not be sufficient, neither would using Add/Remove programs; as files are still leftover from uninstall, and so are registry keys.

Use [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) instead. This will remove all associated files and registry keys. It will call the built in uninstaller first, followed up by a search of leftover files and registry keys.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I uninstalled it with Adobe's uninstaller at http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html and re-installed it with http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer. It didn't work.

Any other ideas? Thanks